# .htaccess re-write works but I want to block domain from displaying origin. IPTables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iptables

I have setup the .htaccess file to rewrite anyone unwanted domains pointing to my VPS - There is only one domain left that gets mod-rewritten. I want to completly block this Domain from even accessing my origin IP address so I need help with the IP Tables - and how to stop targetdomain.com linking to my site!

Can anyone tell me what needs to be done on the Origin Server to deny access and forwarding from the target domain!

Comment: You can't stop someone else from having a DNS entry pointing to your server, but you could create a VirtualHost for that domain name, and configure that VirtualHost to always serve an error page for any URL. iptables doesn't deal with domain names -- you won't be able to use it to block a domain name.

Comment: what would I use for the virtual host code to stop a certain DNS pointing?

Comment: converting this into an answer so I have room to explain, give me one moment...

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop someone else from having a DNS entry pointing to your server, but you could create a VirtualHost for that domain name, and configure that VirtualHost to always serve an error page for any URL. You mentioned iptables, but iptables doesn't deal with domain names -- you won't be able to use it to block a domain name.

Here's a very simple VirtualHost configuration you might put in your Apache config files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/some/folder"
    # You can only have one ServerName which is the main domain that 
    # you want to block, but if you have additional domains to block,
    # you can add them with ServerAlias directives.
    ServerName baddomain.com
    ServerAlias another.baddomain.com

    # This redirects all requests on this domain to index.html, so
    # that visitors will see your message no matter what path they
    # go to.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, inside the folder `/path/to/some/folder` (which you should replace with an actual folder path on your server), just create an index.html file with whatever message you want to show to anyone who visits this domain.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocked domain</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Blocked domain</h1>
  <p>The domain name you tried to connect to is blocked.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could have it redirect them to another website or whatever else -- read up on mod_alias or mod_rewrite for info on how to do this.

Comment: Hi i really do need help with this - can you add me on anything, nothing works - I dont even know if my bloody .htaccess is working - I have no idea what im doing with any of this getting so confused and stress